# Failed to load parser 'babel-eslint' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app'

Tags: node.js, .net-core

I am getting below error when trying run nodejs application -

**Failed to load parser 'babel-eslint' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app': Cannot find module 'babel-eslint'**

I tried to upgrade eslint but noting is working.

Here is my package.json files -

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.11.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@nadavshaar/react-grid-table": "^1.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "~4.6.1",
    "jquery": "~3.6.0",
    "merge": "^2.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "oidc-client": "~1.11.5",
    "react": "~16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router": "~5.2.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
    "react-router-dom": "~5.3.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.12.0",
    "react-toast-notifications": "^2.5.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "~8.10.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.9.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "nan": "^2.14.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/"
  },
```

Comment: When I run into errors like this, I sometimes have to re-run `npm install`, sometimes I have to delete the package.lock and node_modules, or sometimes even delete the entire local repository, re-download from HEAD (if it's in git), and then `npm install` on a fresh copy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried delete package.lock file and node_module folder but I am getting same error.